# Get $_GET[] parameters part from URL

Tags: php, url, get

I have this type of url:

```
http://mysite.com/results.php?location=montreal&car-rental=no&add-hotel=no&moods%5B%5D=Adventure&moods%5B%5D=Arts&moods%5B%5D=Culture&moods%5B%5D=Well-being&moods%5B%5D=Zen&weather-dependent=yes
```

In PHP, what's the best way to get only the `$_GET[]` part ?

Fo example:

```
$get = location=montreal&car-rental=no&add-hotel=no&moods%5B%5D=Adventure&moods%5B%5D=Arts&moods%5B%5D=Culture&moods%5B%5D=Well-being&moods%5B%5D=Zen&weather-dependent=yes
```

Thanks.

Comment: `explode` on questionmark?

Comment: You mean the query string?  `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` [familiarize yourself with the contents of `$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you searching something like:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're looking for this:

```
$str = 'http://mysite.com/results.php?location=montreal&car-rental=no&add-hotel=no&moods%5B%5D=Adventure&moods%5B%5D=Arts&moods%5B%5D=Culture&moods%5B%5D=Well-being&moods%5B%5D=Zen&weather-dependent=yes';

$query = parse_url($str, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $arr);
print_r($arr);

/*
Array
(
    [location] => montreal
    [car-rental] => no
    [add-hotel] => no
    [moods] => Array
        (
            [0] => Adventure
            [1] => Arts
            [2] => Culture
            [3] => Well-being
            [4] => Zen
        )

    [weather-dependent] => yes
)
*/
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/IyJ8s1HX).

Explanation: [parse_url($str, PHP_URL_QUERY)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) extracts the query string from that url, and [parse_str($query, $arr)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), well, parses it, filling `$arr` variable with `key` => `value` pairs.